# What fruit is this

Tags: identification

It came off of a tree similar to an oak tree in Jacksonville Florida
[image: picture of large green fruit]

A little over 2 inches long

Comment: What makes you think it's edible? There's a gardening stack exchange that does generic plant (and plant matter) identification questions that might get a better response...

Comment: Hi Carolyn, you had posted this on a cooking site. We only do fruit identification when it's a culinary fruit, e.g. if you bought something at a market. I migrated the question to our sister gardening site, maybe they will have an idea what this plant is. You may get better results if you can say something about the size, and possibly include pictures of the tree leaves and bark.

Comment: Could you add a photo of the tree it came from, preferably with a photo of some of the leaves?

Comment: A Google Lens search suggests to me that it could be creeping fig: [SOLVED: Vine with bell-shaped fruit growing in central Texas](https://davesgarden.com/community/forums/t/1381383/#post_9978220), but I am no botanist. Anyone who's sure is welcome to use that information to make an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of an 'official' reply, I maybe can point the OP to the University of Florida IFAS Extension site talking at length about the rather wide variety of figs now established in Florida.

[THE FIG, Uni of Florida](https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/publication/MG214)

The OP referred to the tree as looking like an oak and indeed the leaf morphology of many varieties/cultivars do resemble an oak leaf.

Since her example came off a random tree, perhaps one self seeded, it might simply be a crazy non-cultivated hybrid of any 2 of the many varieties but its shape and in colouration does resemble the ones quoted as examples :

[image: Figs of many colours]

The fruit does not look in any fit condition to eat and should probably be discarded into a compost heap or worm bin to be sustainable I guess.